# Reset de Array sin borrar el valor del item seleccionado

Tags: angular, ionic

Estimados tengo un arreglo de objetos, el cual se lista en un ion-list-option, se lista sin problemas, el ion-list me da la opción de tener un botón cancelar el cual he creado un método para resetear ese ion-list al valor por defecto que es su label, funciona pero cada vez que selecciono un item al volver a desplegar el listado el ítem que seleccione se borra de la lista o arreglo, el método que uso es el que ocasiona eso por que utilizó un null para resetear, eso provoca el borrado del item seleccionado, como puedo hacer el reset sin perder el valor del item que selecciono, dejare unas imágenes y códigos. espero quede claro y me puedan ayudar Gracias.

```js
//arreglo servicio y envio de data por BehaviorSubject, para compartir data entre componetes
const amounts: any[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    amount: 10000
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    amount: 15000
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    amount: 20000
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    amount: 25000
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    amount: 25500
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    amount: 25600
  }
]



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BipService {

  private amount$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(amounts)

  get selectedAmount$():Observable<any> {
    return this.amount$.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


}
```

```js
// componente donde se recibe la data y metedo para hacer el reset del arreglo


@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-amount',
  templateUrl: './payment-amount.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-amount.page.scss'],
})
export class PaymentAmountPage implements OnInit {

  amountSelected:any;
  amounts:any[] = [];

  constructor(private bipService:BipService,
              ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAmount()
    
  }
 
 // se obtiene el arreglo del servicio la data
  getAmount() {
    this.bipService.selectedAmount$.subscribe((resp:any) => {
      this.amounts = resp;
        console.log(resp)
    })
  }
  
  //metodo para resetar el listado del arreglo

  onCancel() {
    this.amountSelected.amount = null;
  }



 






}
```

```html
<div class="text-drop">
  <p>Selecciona otro monto</p>
</div>
<ion-item class="div-drop" lines="none">
  <ion-label>Otro monto</ion-label>
  <ion-select mode="ios" interface="action-sheet" (ionCancel)="onCancel()" cancel- text="Cancelar" [(ngModel)]="amountSelected" (ionChange)="isValidAmount()">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of amounts" [value]="item">
      {{item.amount | currency:'CLP': 'symbol-narrow': '1.0-0'}}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

listado completo al obtener el array del servicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Listado con el item borrado al seleccionar el metodo onCancel()